# How to access a security critical field from an anonymous delegate or lambda?

Tags: c#, .net, security, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

### Scenario

Let's say we've the next code:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public void SomeMethod()
{
    SomeCriticalClass critical = new SomeCriticalClass();

    Action someDelegate = () => 
    {
         critical.Do();
    }

    someDelegate();
}
```

1. The `SomeMethod` signature has `[SecuritySafeCritical]` attribute.
2. `SomeCriticalClass` is some class that has the `[SecurityCritical]` attribute either in the class or method `Do` method-level.
3. We create an anonymous delegate auto-inferred to `Action`.

### Problem

Calling `critical.Do()` causes a <strike>`MethodAccessException`</strike> `FieldAccessException` because a security transparent method (the anonymous method) is trying to access a security critical field (the `critical` SomeCriticalClass local variable).

### Question

***How you overcome this?***

The easy way would be implementing an actual method marked with `[SecuritySafeCritical]` instead of using an anonymous delegate. But this moves us to pre-anonymous delegates and lambas era. *I don't want this.*

Other easy way would be just *don't using security transparency*. **This isn't a solution.**

Almost any available libraries both from Microsoft and open source community aren't designed with security transparency in mind. That is, any own custom code must interoperate with third-party libraries through `[SecuritySafeCritical]` or `[SecurityCritical]` methods/properties/delegates.

Actually I believe that security transparency is a good tool because it forces better and secure software designs, critical actions are very localized and the rest of the code works with minimal permissions.

Comment: In the specific case you've given, it's not clear that you need a lambda at all. You could just use `Action someDelegate = critical.Do;` couldn't you?

Comment: look at MSDN on this issue.. google the ERROR just as I did to get you to a good starting point on how to resolve this issue. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264475.aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233102.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm my real-world scenario isn't that easy. Well, I can do it, but this wouldn't be in a single place, but in a lot of places. This is very bad because using security transparency prevents me from using modern and compact anonymous lambda delegates which saves a lot of code lines and makes the code smaller and yet readable.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: As you say at the bottom of your question - "critical actions are very localized" - if you don't have many places to do this, you can keep *most* of your code "modern", and just have more verbose code in a few places

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thanks for your contribution, but I really know how security transparency works. I'm asking this question because this is a real limitation of using it.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right. But I told that talking more about custom code rather than third-parties' one. In my own code, [SecurityCritical] is very localized. But, what about the rest of others' code? Most of them aren't marked with [AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers], or in other words: it's always [SecurityCritical]. Imagine that you use such libraries a lot, how many calls without using modern and compact lambadas will you need?

Comment: @JonSkeet In fact, in my real-world scenario I can _localize_ the old-style delegates pointing to _named_ methods, because basically all third-party libraries are abstracted using inversion of control. BTW, I'm asking this question because I thought that could be an alternative approach or just to determine that there's no workaround and maybe some C# developer team member on Microsoft reads this question and future .NET versions try to support this scenario. Who knows.

Comment: Please check everyone an update to my question: it's about a `FieldAccessException`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Have you checked my own answer to this question? I believe it can be useful since it's an unexpected behavior or, at least, who could thought that [SecuritySafeCritical] on class level would solve a problem about methods' body code.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: No, I haven't yet. Glad it's sorted it though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, thanks. I'm glad because I could find this solution because... do you remember the point of using _modern approaches_ and still work with partially-trusted code? :D Well, now, happy new year.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sorry but I couldn't wait for other answerers... I got the solution!

By experimentation I could determine that marking with `[SecuritySafeCritical]` the class having the method that creates the anonymous method in its body, **does the trick!!**

In other words, or *talking about the code*:

```
[SecurityCritical]
public class SomeCriticalClass
{
      [SecurityCritical]
      public void Do()
      {
      }
}

[SecuritySafeCritical]
public sealed class SomeClass
{
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
          SomeCriticalClass critical = new SomeCriticalClass()

          // No more FieldAccessException!
          Action action = () => critical.Do();         
    }
}
```

I want to make some clarifications:

- Marking the class `SomeClass` with `[SecuritySafeCritical]` doesn't mean that **all declared methods will be `[SecuritySafeCritical]` by default**. *It means that the class can be used by partially-trusted callers*. You still need to mark with `[SecuritySafeCritical]` attribute those methods, properties or fields that can be accessed by partially-trusted callers.
- It seems that `[SecuritySafeCritical]` at class-level makes local variables and anonymous methods (maybe anonymous objects too!) security safe critical.

***Yes!*** *I hope both my question and my own answer will be useful for everyone, because I believe that the situation described in my question can happen often!*

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers No problem! I'm glad it's useful for other stackoverflowers! ;)

Comment: Does not that seem to be a security hole? If your hidden implementation of anonymous method is marked as SecuritySafeCritical, anyone with sufficient privileges (ReflectionPermission with the ReflectionPermissionFlag.MemberAccess flag) can call it.

Comment: @LOST Maybe you're right. BTW, it has passed a long time since this issue and I'm not sure if in my case I wouldn't have that security hole at all..